# GridColumnDefinition is property but it is used like a type

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm trying to write code in WPF which creates a stackpanel automatically but I don't know how to define a row or a column in code cs.

The XAML:

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="221"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="459" Margin="115,111,0,0">
        <Grid Height="auto" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="153"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Content="Nom Commercial" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic"  FontWeight="Bold"   />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="prix "   FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Quantité"   FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public void creat_stackpanel()
{ 
  StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel; 
  Grid mygrid= new Grid(); 
  Grid.RowDefinition grd= new Grid.RowDefinition(); 
  RowDefinition rd=new RowDefinition(); 
  Grid.ColumnDefinitions gcd=new Grid.ColumnDefinitions(); 
  ColumnDefinition cd=new ColumnDefinition(); 
  Label mylabel1=new Label(); 
  mylabel1.Grid.column =0; 
  mylabel1.Grid.Row=0; 
  mylabel1.Content="Nom Commercial"; 
  myStackPanel.Children.Add(mygrid); 
  myStackPanel.Children.Add(mylabel1); 
  this.Content = myStackPanel; 
}
```

Comment: this is the code xaml

Comment: here is the code cs(i couldn't write it above )

Comment: public void creat_stackpanel(){
        StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel;
Grid mygrid= new Grid();
            Grid.RowDefinition grd= new Grid.RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rd=new RowDefinition();
            Grid.ColumnDefinitions gcd=new Grid.ColumnDefinitions();
            ColumnDefinition cd=new ColumnDefinition();
       Label mylabel1=new Label();
  mylabel1.Grid.column =0;
  mylabel1.Grid.Row=0;
  mylabel1.Content="Nom Commercial";
myStackPanel.Children.Add(mygrid);
myStackPanel.Children.Add(mylabel1);
this.Content = myStackPanel;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RowDefinitions is RowDefinitionCollection property of grid, so you have to add new RowDefinition instance to this collection. Here's a little sample:

```
        Grid mygrid = new Grid();
        RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
        mygrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
        ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition();
        mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);

        Label mylabel1 = new Label();
        mylabel1.Content = "Nom Commercial";

        Grid.SetColumn(mylabel1, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(mylabel1, 0);

        mygrid.Children.Add(mylabel1);
        myStackPanel.Children.Add(mygrid);
```

And xaml part:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel"/>
```